# Undefined reference to opencv dnn on QtCreator

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, qt-creator

**Error**

Unable to link OpenCV DNN module with QtCreator : */home/joseph/Documents/dev/dnn_opencv/utils.cpp:52: error: undefined reference to `cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::Net()*

**Context**

Hi, I am trying to load some models with OpenCV DNN (OpenCV 4.4.0) module in order to do some classification/segmentation as part of a bigger project.
To do so I am using QtCreator (5.15.0) and gpp (10.1.0). OpenCV was built from source with the OpenCV-contrib.

My .pro file looks like that :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include/opencv4"

LIBS += -L"/usr/local/lib/" \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_core
-lopencv_dnn


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    utils.cpp

HEADERS += \
  utils.hpp
```

The project is very simple so far, I am able to prompt images with OpenCV so it seems the usual libraries are being found. However whenever I use something within the DNN module I have this error : */home/joseph/Documents/dev/dnn_opencv/utils.cpp:52: error: undefined reference to `cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::Net()*
This is happening calling `cv::dnn::Net net;` using namespace or not.

I have noticed that in the file */usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/dnn/version.hpp* that there is a flag `#define OPENCV_DNN_API_VERSION 20200609` which corresponds to the dnn version where the Net class is to be found but I don't know where this could lead me.

I don't have much experience with Qmake and OpenCV so it's probably a simple fix but I'd appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: did you try running your code on a simple console project?

Comment: Yes I tried compiling manually with `g++ main.cpp utils.cpp -o output  `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`` , the `-lopencv-dnn` is indeed in --libs but I have the same kind of issue. Actually whenever I try to do some forward propagation the error on the net kind of disappear and I have `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:100:72: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<cv::Formatted>::shared_ptr(const char*&)’` 
It could be that the contrib hasn't been properly built, do you know how I coucld check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are facing the same kind of issue, I managed to install it correctly and use it in QtCreator using the Cmake GUI and checking out all the correct flags. I believe it was an installation mistake regarding the OpenCV-contrib modules.
This link is a good tutorial to mark the correct flags : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/

Also, the weird error I had regarding the `error: no matching function for call to std::shared_ptr<cv::Formatted>::shared_ptr(const char*&)` was only due to a call to a `print(...)` instead of `printf` or `cout`.